# string interpolation java 1.3 and below(if possible)?

Tags: java, format, interpolation

I have a simple string, where I need to insert a few numbers and strings.

Say String a = "My name is %s. I am %d years old".

I also need to insert same number or string at several of these holes.
I need a solution which works for ancient versions of java atleast upto 1.3
I know about String.format (JDK 5+). I read about formatter, my head hurts!!

please help.

Comment: Java 6 is end of the line, Java 1.3, my head hurts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to use [`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) here.

You'd type:

```
String s = "My name is {0}. I am {1} years old";
```

and use the appropriate method to render this to a string. For instance:

```
String ret = MessageFormat.format(s, "John", 32);
```

I'd like to put a link to the javadoc, but... I don't know how much has changed since 1.3! (well, link added, it can't hurt)

(it should be noted that even in 2013, Java's `ResourceBundle`s *still* use `MessageFormat` and read property files in ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8)

Comment: *"it should be noted that even in 2013, Java's ResourceBundles still use MessageFormat and read property files in ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8"* - Obviously that is for reasons of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Maybe, but backwards compatibility has limits... (and this is why I have my own implementation of it, which does `printf()`)

Comment: In Java they will only deliberately break backwards compatibility in order to correct problems that are so severe that they break applications.  This certainly not in that category.  Ergo, it will only be fixed if they can figure out a way to fix it that DOESN'T break compatibility.

Comment: Side note: beware that if you have a missing/badly formatted string/arg mismatch etc, you'll be greeted with an `IllegalArgumentException`...

Answer (score 1):

What about this one

```
String text = "The user {0} has email address {1}."
String msg = MessageFormat.format(text, params);
```

And this other

```
String text = "The user {name} has email address {email}.";
Object[] params = { "nameRobert", "rhume55@gmail.com" };
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put("name", "Robert");
map.put("email", "rhume55@gmail.com");

System.out.println("1st : " + MapFormat.format(text, map));
```